# how to implement blackberry messenger 6 sdk with blackberry eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, sdk, messenger

Im using BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse v1.3 MR and i downloaded blackberry messenger here http://us.blackberry.com/developers/blackberrymessenger/

how to implement this sdk with my eclipse or give me some ideas about how to implement blackberry messenger in my blackberry application?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [documentation link](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/25813/Create_and_setup_the_workspace_eJDE_1391636_11.jsp)

1. In Eclipse®, open the BlackBerry Application Development
   perspective.
2. Click File > New > BlackBerry Project.
3. In the New BlackBerry Project dialog box, in the Project Name field,
   type a name for your project.
4. In the JRE section, make sure you select a BlackBerry® JRE™ that is
   version 6.0 or later, and click Finish.
5. In the Package Explorer view, right-click the project and click
   Properties.
6. In the Properties dialog box, in the left pane, click Java Build
   Path.
7. Click the Libraries tab.
8. Click the Add External JARs button.
9. Navigate to the folder where you extracted the BBM SDK Beta
   4_03_10_2011.zip file.
10. In the BBM SDK folder, double-click net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar.
11. Click Next.
12. In the properties window, click OK.  When you are ready to build
    your project, on the Project menu, click BlackBerry > Package All.

This should do the work.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, if i need only the net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar file only then whats the need of 488MB BBM SDK Beta 4_03_10_2011.zip file???

Comment: @Udhaya I don't know, maybe if you have downloaded it and take a look at the archive.

Comment: @Udhaya I will answer it for you :  3 simulators, which are 485 mb, the MDS simulator used to connect to internet with simulator 26 mb, java docs, sample apps and the jar in question.